# Django - Why doesn't syncdb respect the database router?

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I have set up a database router to direct different apps and different models to different databases using the `db_for_read` and `db_for_write` router methods.

That works very well, except that `./manage.py syncdb` does't respect those router settings.

When I `syncdb` my models, all of them are created in the default database.

The database router only provides an `allow_syncdb` method, but no `sync_to` method. Is there a way to tell the `syncdb` command where to create the new tables?

**Note:** I can't use the `--database` feature, as sometimes some of the model apps go to a different database than the rest of the app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write your router make sure you've written the allow_syncdb() method.  It takes both a database and a model.  When you run `manage.py syncdb` you're essentially setting the `--database=default`.  If you don't want your models to sync to the default database then your allow_syncdb() method should return False for the condition that `db==default and model._meta.app_label==myapp`.

You'll need to run syncdb with the `--database=your_other_db` option to get `myapp` into that db.  But make sure in that case that allow_syncdb() returns True only for the case that `db==your_other_db and model._meta.app_label==myapp`.

Does that make sense?  Basically you have to run the `manage.py syncdb` method twice, once for each database.  You cannot run it only once and have it update both databases.