# Django saving models in different databases

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am new to Django.
I have two apps created in my project:

```
python3 manage.py startapp app1
python3 manage.py startapp app1
```

I am using Mysql as DB and I want that each app should use different schemas.

I try to follow the steps described here:
[Sharing (mysql) database between apps Django with Database routers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031369/sharing-mysql-database-between-apps-django-with-database-routers)

So in *settings.py* I defined 2 MySql schemas and keep default schema and 
add the add the DATABASE_ROUTERS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
    'app2',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mydb1':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'APP1DB',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'mydb2':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'APP2DB',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.dbRouter.App1DBRouter', 'app2.dbRouter.App2DBRouter']
```

Additional files:
app1/models1.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

app2/models2.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And files:
app1/dbRouter.py

```
class App1DBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return 'mydb1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return 'mydb1'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self,obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'app1' and \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'app1':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self,db, model):
        if db == 'mydb1':
            if model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
                return True
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'app1':
            return False
        return None
```

app2/dbRouter.py:

```
class App2DBRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app2':
            return 'mydb2'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self,model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app2':
            return 'mydb2'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self,obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'app2' and \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'app2':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self,db, model):
        if db == 'mydb2':
            if model._meta.app_label == 'app2':
                return True
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'app2':
            return False
        return None
```

After this I expect that when I run commands makemigrations and migrate I would get 2 different tables in 2 different schemas?
So:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'app1':
  app1/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Model1
Migrations for 'app2':
  app2/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Model2


$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app1, app2, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  ...
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

But there are no tables created except *django_migrations* in both schemas.
If I use command:

```
$ python3 manage.py migrate --database=mydb1
```

then both model tables are created in the APP1DB.

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_APP1DB           |
+----------------------------+
| app1_model1                |
| app2_model2                |
| auth_group                 |
```

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate) database routers may implement the method `allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints)` in order to determine whether a certain migration should be performed or not. The methods of custom database routers are always invoked through the default database router [`django.db.router`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/76236f0db2d6afe14c08393cef676f0f3939f7d8/django/db/utils.py#L228):

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, **hints):
    for router in self.routers:
        try:
            method = router.allow_migrate
        except AttributeError:
            # If the router doesn't have a method, skip to the next one.
            continue
        [...]
    return True
```

Because your routers don't define such a method it simply returns `True` at the end of the method and therefore applies the requested migration to the specified database.

You can achieve the separation of apps across the different databases by defining this method:

```
class App1DBRouter(object):
    [...]
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'app1':
            return db == 'mydb1'
        return None
```

And similarly for `app2`.

Comment: To fully work: 
1.) class name should be App1DBRouter 
2.) should be return db == 'mydb1'

Comment: @aeliv002 Thanks, approved. The code was conceptional but you got the idea :-)